# Using "this" vs. not using it in a singleton class for Java?

Tags: java

The following singleton class works fine,

```
public class Elvis
{
    private static Elvis elvis = new Elvis();

    private Elvis()
    {

    }

    public static Elvis Instance()
    {
        return elvis;
    }
}
```

However, when I change `return elvis;` to `return this.elvis`, I get `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. Why is this?

Comment: `this` only exists in the context of an object instance, not in a static context.

Comment: In static context, you can use `Elvis.elvis` instead of `this.elvis`.

Comment: Just how closely did you read the error message? It **exactly** describes the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object instance. A `static` method is not contained in an object, it is contained by the class.

Answer (score 1):

The two keywords "this" and "static" are in some sense antagonic. You use "this" when you're referencing members of the current object, that is you have an object and you, presumably, are acessing an non-static member. Static members, functions and properties, are "globals" for all objects, they don't belong to any specific object but rather to the class itself.

Long history made short. "this" means the current instance of *this* object. Static members don't belong to any instance.